# Type 'Int' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a function:

```
  func rms16(buffer: Int, bufferSize: Int) -> Float
    {
        let sum: Float = 0.0
        let mySize: Int = bufferSize / sizeof(CShort)
        var buffer_short: Int = buffer
        for var i = 0; i < mySize; i++ {
           sum += buffer_short[i] * 2
        }
        let sqrt1: Float = sqrtf(sum / Float(mySize))
        return (sqrt1) / Float(mySize)
    }
```

Above function in a `for` loop it show me error like this:
 Type `Int` has no subscript members

Anyone tell me how can i fix it?

Comment: You declare `buffer_short` as `Int`. That's not an array. That's just an integer.

Comment: Did you mean `[Int]` instead of `Int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `buffer_short` is an integer variable not an array of integer.
You need to change the first argument of your function to an array of integer, like:

```
func rms16(buffer: [Int], bufferSize: Int) -> Float
{
    let sum: Float   = 0.0
    let mySize: Int  = bufferSize / sizeof(CShort)
    var buffer_short = buffer

    for var i = 0; i < mySize; i++
    {
       sum += buffer_short[i] * 2
    }
    let sqrt1: Float = sqrtf(sum / Float(mySize))
    return (sqrt1) / Float(mySize)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..my objective c code:                                                        -( float ) rms16: (signed char*) buffer  bufferSize:(NSUInteger) bufferSize
{
    float sum = 0.0;
    NSUInteger mySize = bufferSize / sizeof(short);
    short *buffer_short = (short*)buffer;
    
    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < mySize; i++)
    {
       sum += (float)(buffer_short[i] * buffer_short[i]);
    }
    
    float sqrt1 = sqrtf( sum / mySize );
    
    return (float)(sqrt1)/mySize;
}    in that buffer is not a array..

Comment: @Donal: So your first parameter is a *pointer* to a buffer, and not an integer. – Please add all relevant information to the question itself!

Answer (score 0):

Your comments indicate that the first parameter should be a *pointer* to a character buffer. The corresponding Swift type is `UnsafePointer<CChar>`. Note also that you are multiplying by `2`
instead of squaring in your Swift code, and that `sum` must be 
declared as a *variable*.

So your Swift function would be

```
func rms16(buffer: UnsafePointer<CChar>, bufferSize: Int) -> Float
{
    var sum: Float = 0.0
    let mySize = bufferSize / sizeof(CShort)

    // Create a pointer to a buffer of `CShort` elements from the given pointer:
    let buffer_short = UnsafeBufferPointer<CShort>(start: UnsafePointer(buffer), count: mySize)

    for var i = 0; i < mySize; i++ {
        sum += pow(Float(buffer_short[i]), 2)
    }
    let sqrt1  = sqrtf(sum / Float(mySize))
    return (sqrt1) / Float(mySize)
}
```

The summation loop can be reduced (!) to:

```
let sum = buffer_short.reduce(0.0, combine: { $0 + pow(Float($1), 2)} )
```